# CURL post could not upload csv data to blaynmail

Tags: php, csv, curl, file-upload

```
$file = "blaynmailhahaha.csv";
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer [".$response."]";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.toku-maga.com/rest/1.0/contact/import/create");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0); // use HTTP/1.0 instead of 1.1
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // uncomment this line if you get no gateway 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [$authorization, 'Content-Type: text/plain']);
$cfile = new CurlFile($file,  'text/csv','import');
//curl file itself return the realpath with prefix of @

$data = array('data-binary' => $cfile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($cfile);
//echo "<br>Data File  : " . $cfile ;
echo "<br>This is Access_token : " . $authorization ;
echo "<br>This is 2nd Output : " . $curl_response ;
```

I don't get any response from $curl_response and could not upload it to blaynmail. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You have no response but what does [`curl_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) output?

Comment: There is no output in the curl_error.